# не записывает в базу данных

Tags: php

```
         <input class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Введите ваше имя"><br>

         <input class="form-control" name="dp_artist" placeholder="Введите ваш пароль"><br>

         <button class="btn btn-success"  type ="submit" >########</button>
```

`` require_once 'vendor/connect.php';   

$gl_artist = $_POST['gl_artist'];
$dp_artist = $_POST['dp_artist'];
$name = $_POST['name'];


    mysqli_query($connect, 'INSERT INTO `reliz` (`gl_artist`, `dp_artist`, `name`) VALUES ($gl_artist,$dp_artist,$name)'); ``

?>

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В запросе строковые значения берутся в кавычки или лучше использовать плейсхолдеры ( [Подготавливаемые запросы](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) ). А откуда материализуется `$_POST['gl_artist']`, вообще не понятно

Answer (score 0):

Просто ошибка в синтаксисе. Вот так надо:

```
mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `reliz` (`gl_artist`, `dp_artist`, `name`) VALUES 
('$gl_artist','$dp_artist','$name')");
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]